# Sort one array compared to another, and then sort within that array

Tags: perl, sorting

I have two arrays which need sorting.

For example, I might have the following:

`@aa = (1, 4, 5, 1, 2);`
`@bb = (3, 1, 2, 2, 3);`

The following script sorts the elements in `@aa`, and then rearranges `@bb`, as follows:

`my @idx = sort { $aa[$a] cmp $aa[$b] } 0 .. $#aa;`

`@aa = @aa[@idx];`

`@bb = @bb[@idx];`

This leaves `@bb` as `(3, 2, 3, 1, 2)`.

However, I now want to rearrange the elements in `@bb` so that those that correspond to the same values in `@aa` are in ascending order. For example, the first 3 and 2 in `@bb`, both correspond to a 1 in `@aa`, and so I want to be able to swap them around, so `@bb = (2, 3, 3, 1, 2)`.

Is there an easy way to do this. I had thought about a new array where I multiple each pairs of elements in `@aa` and `@bb` together, and then using that, but can't see how that would help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sorting numbers, you should be using `<=>`, not `cmp`.

It sounds to me like you are asking to modify your sort  to sort by the bb values when the aa values are equal.   This is simply:

```
my @idx = sort {
    $aa[$a] <=> $aa[$b] ||
    $bb[$a] <=> $bb[$b]
} 0 .. $#aa;
```

Comment: Yes - it should've been <=> and not cmp.

Just changed my script and it works perfectly. So easy too!